# How to Access Database hosted on localhost sql server 2008r2 by another computer in LAN

Tags: sql-server, lan

I created a windows form application in which I used an SQL server database.

It is working fine on my computer. Now I want to run this application on another computer that is connected with LAN with my computer.

The problem is both application must share the same database. I don't want to host my database online.

Please tell me how to access the same database from different computers by using LAN or another technique.

Comment: what is your connection url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set up the SQL server to allow access from within the LAN.

You may also have to set up the firewall on your server to allow access to the SQL server port(s), usually 1433 1434 for MS SQL server.

Then point your application on the client machines to the server's IP address within your lan. Usually something like 192.168.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

Find the folder where your DB files are. **SHARE** that folder to '*Everyone*' in network.
Turn**Off** Windows Firewall (this can be a problem sometimes when it's turned on).

Be sure that your second PC has the same `ConnectionString` (ServerName, ex. //PC-NAME/SQLEXPRESS) and is watching into your 'server' computer (PC with database on it).

Comment: why do you need to share the database files? I have this setup running and never had to do anything like that? It only makes sense if you have another sql-server accessing it, which is not the case

Comment: Huum, wierd, I had a lot of problems if my DB file is not in shared folder, that's why I wrote that should be done also.